# Determine if a row for an fk exists in any one of 20 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to determine a better way than so many IF/THEN statements to determine if ONE OR MORE tables contain a ref to a forign key.  I simply need to know (true/false) if a row exists in any one of 20 tables. All tables have the same fk field.

I hope this makes sense, if not i'll try to explain further.

Comment: SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS and SYS.TABLES...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Would the following improve your situation?

```
if exists(select * from Table1 where ForeignKeyColumn = searchValue)
  or exists(select * from Table2 where ForeignKeyColumn = searchValue)
  or exists(select * from Table3 where ForeignKeyColumn = searchValue)
  or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 20 tables remains consistant then what about using a left outer join to each of the tables.  probably inefficient way of doing it but should work

```
select Id from 
    (Select PK.id, isnull(tbl1.fk,0) as fk1, isnull(tbl2.fk,0) as fk2 ... etc
    from pk left join tbl1 on pk.id = tbl1.fk left join
        tbl2 on pk.id = tbl2.fk ... etc) as VirtualTable
Where fk1>0 or fk2>0 ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to work out if you can remove a particular row?

So... perhaps try:

```
begin tran;
delete tablename
where id = 3;
rollback tran;
```

Then see what error you get (if any), and how many rows are affected.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
if exists (
 select * from Table1 where MyKey = @key
 union
 select * from Table2 where MyKey = @key
 union
 select * from Table3 where MyKey = @key
 ...
)
```

I don't have a SQL server instance open in front of me so I'm sure that's got a syntax error somewhere, but you get the idea =)

Comment: might want union all to improve speed, since you are only cheking forexistance not returning information